# How do you deal with having multiple storage_os_disk blocks in Terraform for an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am currently using Terraform to spin up a VM in Microsoft Azure. I am required to have 4 different disk drivers on the VM.

To spin it up in AWS I used `ebs_block_device` and it seems that `storage_os_disk` is the Azure equivalent.

In examples I have seen it seems that only one `storage_os_disk` block is allowed? Is this correct? If so, how would you recommend dealing with the four drivers I require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to have more than 1 OS disk, you should use data_disk (thats what its called in azure). Terraform seem to show these examples:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment.html
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html#storage_data_disk

Note, you can use either one of those, NOT BOTH.